# How should I traverse my ontology model?

Tags: semantics, rdf, jena

How can I traverse my ontology file? I want to get the subclasses of the class Shape and the properties associated with it. I have seen the example of traversing the Pizza ontology file but I'm not able to manipulate for my purpose. I'm getting a lot of errors.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>


<!DOCTYPE rdf:RDF [
<!ENTITY owl "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" >
<!ENTITY xsd "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" >
<!ENTITY rdfs "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" >
<!ENTITY rdf "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" >
<!ENTITY SBIRS "http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#" >
]> 


<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#"
 xml:base="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl"
 xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
 xmlns:SBIRS="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#"
 xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
 xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
<owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl"/>



<!-- 
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Object Properties
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 -->




<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasArmBone -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;hasArmBone">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;hasShape"/>
    <owl:inverseOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;isArmBoneOf"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasCranialBones -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;hasCranialBones">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;hasSkullBone"/>
    <owl:inverseOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;isFacialBoneOf"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasEthmoidBones -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;hasEthmoidBones">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;hasCranialBones"/>
    <owl:inverseOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;isTemporalBoneOf"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasFacialBones -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;hasFacialBones">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;hasSkullBone"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasForeArmsBones -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;hasForeArmsBones">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;hasArmBone"/>
    <owl:inverseOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;isForeArmBoneOf"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasFrontalBones -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;hasFrontalBones">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;hasCranialBones"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasHumerusBones -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;hasHumerusBones">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;hasArmBone"/>
    <owl:inverseOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;isArmBoneOf"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasInferiornasalBones -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;hasInferiornasalBones">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;hasFacialBones"/>
    <owl:inverseOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;isFacialBoneOf"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasLacrimalBones -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;hasLacrimalBones">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;hasFacialBones"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasMandibleBones -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;hasMandibleBones">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;hasFacialBones"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasMaxilaBones -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;hasMaxilaBones">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;hasFacialBones"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasNasalBones -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;hasNasalBones">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;hasFacialBones"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasOccipitalBones -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;hasOccipitalBones">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;hasCranialBones"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasParietalBones -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;hasParietalBones">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;hasCranialBones"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasRadiusBones -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;hasRadiusBones">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;hasForeArmsBones"/>
    <owl:inverseOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;isRadiusBoneof"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasRibsBones -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;hasRibsBones">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;haschestBone"/>
    <owl:inverseOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;isSternumboneOf"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasShape -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;hasShape">
    <owl:inverseOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;isShapeOf"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasShenoidBones -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;hasShenoidBones">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;hasCranialBones"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasSkullBone -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;hasSkullBone">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;hasShape"/>
    <owl:inverseOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;isSkullBoneOf"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasSternumBones -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;hasSternumBones">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;haschestBone"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasTemporalBones -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;hasTemporalBones">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;hasCranialBones"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasUlnabones -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;hasUlnabones">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;hasForeArmsBones"/>
    <owl:inverseOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;isUlnaBoneOf"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasVomerBones -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;hasVomerBones">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;hasFacialBones"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasZygomativBones -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;hasZygomativBones">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;hasFacialBones"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#haschestBone -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;haschestBone">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;hasShape"/>
    <owl:inverseOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;isChestBoneOf"/>
    <owl:inverseOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;isSkullBoneOf"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isArmBoneOf -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;isArmBoneOf">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;isShapeOf"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isChestBoneOf -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;isChestBoneOf">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;isShapeOf"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isCranialBonOf -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;isCranialBonOf">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;isSkullBoneOf"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isEthmoidboneOf -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;isEthmoidboneOf">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;isCranialBonOf"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isFacialBoneOf -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;isFacialBoneOf">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;isSkullBoneOf"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isForeArmBoneOf -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;isForeArmBoneOf">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;isArmBoneOf"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isFrontalBoneOf -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;isFrontalBoneOf">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;isCranialBonOf"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isHumerusBoneOf -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;isHumerusBoneOf">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;isArmBoneOf"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isInferiornasalBoneOf -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;isInferiornasalBoneOf">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;isFacialBoneOf"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isLacrimalBoneOf -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;isLacrimalBoneOf">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;isFacialBoneOf"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isMandiblBoneOf -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;isMandiblBoneOf">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;isFacialBoneOf"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isMaxilaBoneOF -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;isMaxilaBoneOF">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;isFacialBoneOf"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isNasalBoneOf -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;isNasalBoneOf">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;isFacialBoneOf"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isOccipitalBoneOf -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;isOccipitalBoneOf">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;isCranialBonOf"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isParietalBoneOf -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;isParietalBoneOf">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;isCranialBonOf"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isRadiusBoneof -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;isRadiusBoneof">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;isForeArmBoneOf"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isRibBoneOf -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;isRibBoneOf">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;isChestBoneOf"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isShapeOf -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;isShapeOf"/>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isShenoidBoneOf -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;isShenoidBoneOf">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;isCranialBonOf"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isSkullBoneOf -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;isSkullBoneOf">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;isShapeOf"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isSternumboneOf -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;isSternumboneOf">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;isChestBoneOf"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isTemporalBoneOf -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;isTemporalBoneOf">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;isCranialBonOf"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isUlnaBoneOf -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;isUlnaBoneOf">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;isForeArmBoneOf"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isVomerBoneOf -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;isVomerBoneOf">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;isFacialBoneOf"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isZygomaticBoneOf -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&SBIRS;isZygomaticBoneOf">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;isFacialBoneOf"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- 
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Classes
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 -->




<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#Arm -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="&SBIRS;Arm">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;Shape"/>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#Chest -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="&SBIRS;Chest">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;Shape"/>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#Cranial -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="&SBIRS;Cranial">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;Skull"/>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#FacialBones -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="&SBIRS;FacialBones">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;Skull"/>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#ForeArms -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="&SBIRS;ForeArms">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;Arm"/>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#Humerus -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="&SBIRS;Humerus">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;Arm"/>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#Ribs -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="&SBIRS;Ribs">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;Chest"/>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#Shape -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="&SBIRS;Shape"/>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#Skull -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="&SBIRS;Skull">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;Shape"/>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#Sternum -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="&SBIRS;Sternum">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&SBIRS;Chest"/>
</owl:Class>



<!-- 
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Individuals
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 -->




<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#Ethmoid -->

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&SBIRS;Ethmoid">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&SBIRS;Cranial"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#FrontalBones -->

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&SBIRS;FrontalBones">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&SBIRS;Cranial"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#Inferior_Nasal -->

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&SBIRS;Inferior_Nasal">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&SBIRS;FacialBones"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#Lacrimal -->

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&SBIRS;Lacrimal">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&SBIRS;FacialBones"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#Mandible -->

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&SBIRS;Mandible">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&SBIRS;FacialBones"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#Maxilla -->

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&SBIRS;Maxilla">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&SBIRS;FacialBones"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#Nasal -->

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&SBIRS;Nasal">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&SBIRS;FacialBones"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#Occipital -->

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&SBIRS;Occipital">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&SBIRS;Cranial"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#Parietal -->

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&SBIRS;Parietal">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&SBIRS;Cranial"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#Radius -->

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&SBIRS;Radius">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&SBIRS;ForeArms"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#Sphenoid -->

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&SBIRS;Sphenoid">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&SBIRS;Cranial"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#Temporal -->

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&SBIRS;Temporal">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&SBIRS;Cranial"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#Ulna -->

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&SBIRS;Ulna">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&SBIRS;ForeArms"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#Vomer -->

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&SBIRS;Vomer">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&SBIRS;FacialBones"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#Zygomatic -->

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&SBIRS;Zygomatic">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&SBIRS;FacialBones"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>



<!-- 
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// General axioms
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 -->

<rdf:Description>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;AllDisjointClasses"/>
    <owl:members rdf:parseType="Collection">
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="&SBIRS;Arm"/>
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="&SBIRS;ForeArms"/>
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="&SBIRS;Humerus"/>
    </owl:members>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;AllDisjointClasses"/>
    <owl:members rdf:parseType="Collection">
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="&SBIRS;Chest"/>
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="&SBIRS;Ribs"/>
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="&SBIRS;Sternum"/>
    </owl:members>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;AllDisjointClasses"/>
    <owl:members rdf:parseType="Collection">
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="&SBIRS;Cranial"/>
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="&SBIRS;FacialBones"/>
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="&SBIRS;Skull"/>
    </owl:members>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;AllDisjointClasses"/>
    <owl:members rdf:parseType="Collection">
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="&SBIRS;Arm"/>
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="&SBIRS;Chest"/>
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="&SBIRS;Shape"/>
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="&SBIRS;Skull"/>
    </owl:members>
</rdf:Description>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and then edit this question to increase your chances of getting a good answer.

Answer (score 5):

Was it really necessary to post all 700+ lines of your ontology to ask this question? A little help to trim the question down to its minimal form is always appreciated. Also, if your code has errors it's much easier for us to help you fix it if you, you know, *actually show us the code*.

Anyway, here's a simple program that:

- finds the sbirs:Shape class
- iterates through the sub-classes of that class
- prints the [declared properties](http://incubator.apache.org/jena/documentation/notes/rdf-frames.html) of the sub-class

Code:

```
package example;

import java.util.Iterator;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager;

public class SbirsExample
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        new SbirsExample().run();
    }

    public void run() {
        OntModel m = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM );
        FileManager.get().readModel( m, "src/main/resources/sbirs.owl" );

        String NS = "http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#";

        OntClass shape = m.getOntClass( NS + "Shape" );

        for (Iterator<OntClass> subs = shape.listSubClasses();
             subs.hasNext(); ) {
            OntClass sub = subs.next();

            System.out.println( "sbirs:Shape has sub-class " + sub.getURI() +
                                " with declared properties:" );

            for (Iterator<OntProperty> props = sub.listDeclaredProperties();
                 props.hasNext(); ) {
                OntProperty declared = props.next();
                System.out.println( "   - " + declared );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
sbirs:Shape has sub-class http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#Skull with declared properties:
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasRadiusBones
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isRadiusBoneof
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasInferiornasalBones
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasCranialBones
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasVomerBones
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isMandiblBoneOf
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasOccipitalBones
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isInferiornasalBoneOf
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isCranialBonOf
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasArmBone
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isZygomaticBoneOf
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasShape
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasFacialBones
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasNasalBones
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasHumerusBones
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isLacrimalBoneOf
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isUlnaBoneOf
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasForeArmsBones
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isSkullBoneOf
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isOccipitalBoneOf
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasFrontalBones
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isShenoidBoneOf
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isMaxilaBoneOF
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasSternumBones
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasMaxilaBones
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isShapeOf
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasMandibleBones
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isArmBoneOf
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isFrontalBoneOf
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasZygomativBones
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasLacrimalBones
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasTemporalBones
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isRibBoneOf
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasShenoidBones
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasSkullBone
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#haschestBone
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isChestBoneOf
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isHumerusBoneOf
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isParietalBoneOf
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isTemporalBoneOf
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isEthmoidboneOf
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isFacialBoneOf
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasUlnabones
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasEthmoidBones
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasRibsBones
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isNasalBoneOf
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasParietalBones
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isVomerBoneOf
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isSternumboneOf
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#isForeArmBoneOf
 sbirs:Shape has sub-class http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#Chest with declared properties:
    - http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#hasRadiusBones
    ... etc ...
```